# My program wont run my while loop before it closes

Tags: c, while-loop, logic

So there is no syntax error in my program it's a logic error. My problem is when I try to run it only my `printf` statement will execute but after that it closes my program not letting my `while loop` ask for anymore data until the user puts in `-1` to stop my while loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
// prototypes
void updateLevel(int PlayerPoints, int playerLevels[]);
void displayLevels(int ArrayName[]);

//main begins
int
main (void){
    //arrays and varibles
    int playerLevels[6] = {0};
    int playerPoints = 0;

    printf("Player points (-1 to quit) ");
    scanf("%d" , &playerPoints);
    //while loop to process input data
    while(playerPoints =! -1){
        scanf("Player points (-1 to quit)  %d" , &playerPoints);
        updateLevel(playerPoints, playerLevels);
    }

    displayLevels(playerLevels);
    return(0);
}
//main ends

//functions
void updateLevel(int playerPoints, int playerLevels[]){
    if(playerPoints >=50)
    playerLevels[6]++;
    else if (playerPoints >=40)
        playerLevels[5]++;
    else if (playerPoints >= 30)
        playerLevels[4]++;
    else if (playerPoints >= 20)
        playerLevels[3]++;
    else if (playerPoints >= 10)
        playerLevels[2]++;
    else
        playerLevels[1]++;

}

void displayLevels(int playerLevels[]){
    printf("T O T A L S\n");
    printf("Level 1    %d\n", playerLevels[1]);
    printf("Level 2    %d\n", playerLevels[2]);
    printf("Level 3    %d\n", playerLevels[3]);
    printf("Level 4    %d\n", playerLevels[4]);
    printf("Level 5    %d\n", playerLevels[5]);
    printf("Level 6    %d\n", playerLevels[6]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters instead of this

```
while(playerPoints =! -1){
                   ^^
```

there must be

```
while(playerPoints != -1){
                   ^^
```

The original statement is equivalent to

```
while(playerPoints = 0){
```

so the loop is not executed.

Nevertheless the program has undefined behavior because you defined an array of 6 elements

```
int playerLevels[6] = {0};
```

but you are trying to access memory beyond the array

```
if(playerPoints >=50)
playerLevels[6]++;
```

The valid range of indices for the array is `[0, 5]` Indices start from 0.

Comment: omg i didn't even notice the operator but thank you so much! it works so thank you!

Comment: @GabrielFregoso No problem. It is a typo.:)